# CSS Animation to apply to elements one after the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to use the CSS animation in my project.

everything works as it should. However, when I run my code, the CSS animation get applied to all the elements with the class `.allPro` at the same time.

Is there any way to apply the CSS animation individually?

For example, make the first element appear and then the second one and then third one and so on and so forth?

This is my code on [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z9Lhtgxh/)

And this is my CSS code:

```
.allPro {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
  background-color:#000;
  animation: fadein 2s;
}
@keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0}
  to   { opacity: 1}
}
```

The elements are created dynamically. So I cannot predict how many elements would be on the page.

I am willing to use jQuery to achieve what I'm trying to do.

EDIT:

This is how I get the elements created dynamically on my page and append them to the container:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var poutput = $('.dotted-list');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://mydonain.com/page.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status) {
      $.each(data, function(pi, item) {
        str = item.name;
        if (str.length > 2) str = str.substring(0, 2)
        var products = '<a class="allPro" data-id="' + item.id + '" data-name="' + item.name + '" data-type="' + item.type + '" href="" data-transition="slidefade">' + '<div class="products-feed-Small">' + '<div style="position:absolute; top:40%; text-align:center; width:100%; color:#fff; font-family:Walpurga; font-size:28px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration: none;">' + item.name + '</div>'

        +'<img src="62.jpg" >' + '</div>' + '</a>';
        poutput.append(products);
        $('.allPro').each(function() {
          var delay = $(this).index();
          $(this).css('animation-delay', delay + 's');
        });
        //$( "#load-more" ).show();
      });
    },
    error: function() {
      poutput.text('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok, if the elements are dynamic then you need to use JavaScript. CSS can't help with that. If you are OK to use JS/jQuery, I can give a solution.

Comment: no way of doing this using CSS then?

Comment: Nope because the only CSS way to make it sequential is to add `animation-delay` and when you have dynamic no. of elements, you can't write the selectors for each of them.

Comment: @Harry, would you mind sharing your jQuery solution please?

Comment: If you're willing to consider a jQuery, or plain JavaScript, version please add those tags to your question (use the [edit] link).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this with jQuery (or JavaScript) would be to find the `index` of the element and then set the `animation-delay` based on it like in the below snippet.

One **key thing to note** is that I've added `backwards` (`animation-fill-mode`) to the `animation`. This is required because generally elements will remain in the default state until the animation's delay timer expires. In this case the default state is `opacity: 1` (as there is no `opacity` setting on `.allPro`). It means all elements become visible at once and then when the animation *actually starts*, they blink.

By setting `backwards` as fill mode, we are instructing the UA that during the delay period the elements should hold the state as mentioned in the first keyframe. This change means that the elements get the `opacity: 0` setting as soon as they are appended (because `animation` is added in default selector). So, they start to appear only when the animation is *actually happening* and not before it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('body').append('<div class="allPro"></div>');
  }
  $('.allPro').each(function() {
    var delay = $(this).index();
    $(this).css('animation-delay', delay + 's');
  });
});
```

```css
.allPro {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  animation: fadein 2s backwards;
}
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, even though this works fine... my issue is that all the elements are dynamic and appended into the container using jquery AJAX. so when I use your jQuery code, the elements get appended into the container and then they blink once individually.

Comment: Have you set the `animation-delay` after the AJAX call (and appending of the elements) or before it? You should set it afterwards. If you did that, it should work even though you are using AJAX to append the elements.

Comment: Yes, it is after the AJAX call.

Comment: That's interesting. Can I see a demo somewhere?

Comment: You can @Jackson (or you can give me a link where I can see it). But checkout the edit to my answer. There are no static elements here, I have  appended them dynamically through JS and the solution still works.

Comment: That's very strange.. I don't get why mine works differently to be honest. I've added my ajax call code including your code after the ajax appends the elements to the container.

Comment: I am not an expert when it comes to AJAX and stuff but I can't see much wrong with your code either. When you inspect the elements through Dev Console do you see the `style='animation-delay:...'` setting added and do they all have unique delay values?

Comment: Also, did you add the `backwards` keyword that I've added in the `animation` property's value?

Comment: OMG, Harry... I missed the backward in CSS and when i added it. it worked like a charm.. Thanks for pointing that out...

Comment: Ah, sorry there was a miss on my part too. I should've mentioned it explicitly in the answer because that *was* a change that *I* made. Nevermind, I will edit it in and add an explanation of why I added it also :)

Comment: I should've looked in your CSS as well. lol... hey ho.. it works now and once again, thanks

Comment: @Jackson: I've also added the explanation into the answer now. Let me know if you need any further details on that :)