# How to fade in and out one by one using css animation and angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-animate

Consider the following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rJyLj077H76PdqmdRfic?p=preview)

[image]

I have a list of tile that I want to fade in one by one using `ng-repeat` however the animation fade the entire tile set all together.

Here is my `CSS`

```
.fade-up {
  animation: fadeUpIn 5s ease-in-out;
}

.fade-in {
  animation: fadeUpOut 5s ease-in-out;
}


@keyframes fadeUpIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

Here is my template:

```
<div ng-controller="baseController as bCtrl">
  <button ng-click="bCtrl.toggleStuff()">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <div ng-repeat="group in bCtrl.groupList">
    <div class="tile-style" 
         ng-repeat="tile in group"
         ng-class="{'fade-up': bCtrl.display, 'fade-in': !bCtrl.display}">
      {{tile}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my `JS`

```
    function toggleStuff() {
      self.display = !self.display;
    }
```

Is there a way to fade in the tiles individually?

Comment: This also could help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699636/css-animation-to-apply-to-elements-one-after-the-other/37699816#37699816. It doesn't use Angular but I guess you would be able to get the idea and convert it.

Answer (score 0):

u want it animate one by one, an easy way is to set them to display one by one, custom ng-animate might cost more

u may need to record timeouts and clear when change happen during loop

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  (function(a) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(a); //0,1,2...
      //$scope.list[a].display = false;
      //$scope.$apply()
    }, i * 1000);
  })(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer suggests, you could do this adding timeouts.
I have applied the solution in your plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/RV6E20IP5VLrMDKkOr4G?p=preview

```
for (var i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
            tile = { val: i , display: false };
            if (i % 4 == 0){
              tempList.push(tile);
              self.groupList.push(tempList);
              tempList = []
            } else {
              tempList.push(tile);
            }
            (function(index, tile) {
              $timeout(function() {
                tile.display = true;
              }, i * 400);
            })(i, tile);
          }
```